# UIGestureRecognizer Delegate method is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Trying to make some draggable images in a subview of a scrollview. But nothing happens. Anybody got any ideas why a breakpoint in handlePan is never hit? :'(   Thanks if u can help!

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    twView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"]];
    [self.springView addSubview:twView];
    [twView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60)];

    fbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"]];
    [self.springView addSubview:fbView];
    [fbView setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 60, 60)];

    g1 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [twView addGestureRecognizer:g1];
    g1.delegate = self;

    g2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [fbView addGestureRecognizer:g2];
    g2.delegate = self;

}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    ... do amazing things
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set delegate for it. You have already assigned a selector for a target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have here, it's probably one of two things.  Either your image view doesn't have `userInteractionEnabled` set to yes, or there is another view on top of your image views blocking the gestures.

Comment: Seems UIImageView has userInteractionEnabled set to false by default, when created programatically.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The built-in pan gesture recogniser of UIScrollView subclass is probably intercepting the gesture.

Make sure your view controller implements the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol and implement

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: This answer is also helpful, it seems I had more than one problem. Unfortunately marking two things as correct doesn't seem to work (unsurprisingly) so an upvote will have 2 do :(

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that helps to me, is on instance of gesture recognizer set

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *loginTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonAction)];
loginTap.delegate = self;
[self.loginButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.loginButton addGestureRecognizer:self.loginTap];
```

And after assigning delegate to self, it will receive call in delegate methods